# What does the line of numbers at the very bottom of the copyright page mean?

Tags: publishing, copyright

I wish to finally publish my manuscript and fill in the copyright page, but I notice, in other publications, at the very bottom of the copyright page, is a row of numbers. Or actually, two sets of numbers: one beginning at the left, and another beginning at the right...on the same line.

I figure one may be referring to the number of edition (first edition, etc.), but which set of numbers: the one on the left or the right?

Does one set refer to the "year"? Does one set refer to the printing, but not an editing (edition)?

My book begs to be printed, but I'm at a standstill until informed as to what numbers to print.

[There is [a similar question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/10386/what-are-those-countdown-numbers-on-the-copyright-page), but it doesn't explain this specific configuration.]

**Samples**

14 15 16 17 18/DC/33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 
 copyright 1994

20 21 22 23 24/TSC/31 30 29 28 27 26 25...16 15
 copyright 2006

28 29 30 31 --- 19 18 17 16
copyright 1999

Comment: Can you provide an example of the numbers you're referring to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are those "countdown" numbers on the copyright page?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/10386/what-are-those-countdown-numbers-on-the-copyright-page)

Comment: @Ben - No.  I already referenced this other question in my Question explanation. It does not deal with two sets of numbers, back to back, in the same line.

Comment: As long as you don't provide an image of the complete copyright page, we can only guess. Please [edit your answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/posts/69040/edit) and offer a visual example.

Comment: Your question is, what numbers to use in your own book. Why do you insist to follow an example that you don't understand? That makes absolutely no sense. Either follow the convention (10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1) or, as recommended in my answer, do not use print run numbers at all. You don't need them in self-publishing. In any case, there is no reason to let your inability to understand what some numbers in some random book mean hold up your book production.

Comment: @F1Krazy - See samples above. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Ben - See samples above. Thank you for your input.

Comment: As I said, could you please post **an *image* of the *whole* copyright page**? And please give the title and author, if those aren't discernible from the copyright page.

Comment: You ask what numbers to use. Speak to your printer. Or if you're printing direct from digital (with a print on demand service, etc) just use a single number for the edition, or any other numbers you find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Any tiny, unexplained set of numbers on their own line on the copyright page signify the *reprints* of this specific edition. For example, the third edition from 2001 may have been reprinted seven times. Then the numbers will look something like this:

> 10 9 8 7
> (originally that line will have looked like this: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 4 3 2 1, and then for each reprint one number was deleted from the right of that row)

or:

> 8 10 9 7
> (originally: 2 4 6 8 10 9 7 5 3 1, deleted from both ends; this schema is used to keep the numbers centered on the page)

or any other schema this particular publisher uses.

The line of numbers was invented when reprints were made from film or printing plates, and instead of making a new film or plate for each reprint, the no longer correct number was scratched out. Old books, that were set in lead letters don't have this row because the relevant letters could more easily be exchanged. In old books (and in some books today), you will find something like this:

> Seventh Printing, October 2016
> (originally: First printing, January 2001)

Today, where printing is often direct from digital, some publishers no longer use this row of numbers and instead use a single number (e.g. Penguin Random House). Here you will see something like this:

> 7
> (originally: 1)

If your numbers look significantly different, you'll have to provide a visual example of the whole copyright page.

---

The purpose of these numbers is for the publisher to know which print run a specific book belongs to, if they notice problems with it. The numbers are irrelevant for anyone outside the publishing house (except book collectors).

As a self-publisher, you don't usually need this row of numbers, as (a) you probably don't have a quality management in your publishing process and (b) your books will likely be print on demand, where there are no print runs and no reprinting.

Comment: @ Ben - The samples you give are not in my library's books.  See new samples added to in my Question. Thank you.